# How do browsers determine which exact colors to use for border: inset or outset?

Tags: css

If I specify `border: 1px outset blue;` as the style for an element, the browser renders two different border colors: one for the top and left borders, and another for the bottom and right borders.

```css
li
  { border: 10px outset #0000FF;
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: #0000FF;
    width: 30%;
    }

p
  { margin: 1em 2em;
    text-align: center;
    }
```

```html
<li><p>Hi!</p></li>
```

**Given a single color specified for the border, how does the browser determine which colors to render the border in?**  Alternately, given a graphical comp (a .PSD for example) that shows an outset border with two different colors, how can I choose a single border color to specify to get the closest results to the comp?

Comment: Good question, considering that there's [no standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#border-color-properties) for this calculation meaning each browser vendor gets to decide how to calculate these colors.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is no one algorithm [specified by CSS](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#value-def-outset):

> UAs may choose their own algorithm to calculate the actual colors used.

Different browsers do significantly different things:

- Firefox blends the highlight border with full white (about 57%) and the lowlight border with full black (about 68%).
- Opera blends the borders with white and black less strongly (25% each).
- WebKit (Safari, Chrome) blends the lowlight border to black (33%) whilst leaving the highlight border as the untouched stated colour.
- IE splits the width of the border in two when you use inset/outset. The inside half of the border has a lowlight shade of 75% black and an untouched highlight colour. The outside half of the border has a highlight colour shaded 25% to black and a lowlight colour shaded 50% to black. This has the effect of reproducing the border style of the Windows 9x/NT4/2000 button if the border-width is 2px.

Unfortunately you cannot get consistent results out of inset/outset/groove/ridge borders. Often the results are different but still OK across browsers; if that's not good enough you'll need to specify each border side colour explicitly.

Comment: On IE, which set of borders applies when the border width is 1 pixel?

Comment: The outer. (The outer borders get the spare pixel whenever there's an odd number of pixels.)

Comment: It’s curious that [CSS3 Borders](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/) omits that point entirely.

Comment: Thanks for the details!  I think it'll be easiest to skip the outset style and just specify the desired colors for top/left and bottom/right.

Comment: @KatieK You could do whatever you want with CSS3 property border-image and keep a fallback for IE6-7-... with conditional comments